leave Filedialog window open after selecting a file
In my VBA application, I'm opening a FileDialog and waiting for the user to select a file.
FileDialog.Show displays the contents of the folder and waits until the user makes a selection. Once the user selects a file, the window that lists the files closes.
After they have selected a file I run a VBA command to open the file they selected.
Question: Is there a way to leave the display of the contents of the folder open so a user could select another file from the list (and open it), without closing the window and reopening it (by calling the FileDialog.Show command again)? On our network server, there is a 10-20 second delay opening the folder in the first place and it would speed up users' interaction with the system if the list of files in the folder just remained open, so they could double-click another file from the window and open it.

I don't think so. Maybe AllowMultiselect is an option, so that the user can select all the files at once?

There is a way. -1- The first time the user selects a file, you loop thru the selected directory (!) with the command Dir(). -2- Store the results - the files and paths of subfolders - into a comma seperated string. -3- create a seperate form where you have a listbox. -4- open the form, even with acDialog. -5- feed the stored results as rowsource of the listbox. -6- put some code in the name_of_listbox_Click() event.

Direct answer: No. But a work-around has been suggested.

Good suggestion. Thanks. Also, an option would be to read the list of files into a temp table and display the filenames on a form, which would allow a user to sort them, etc. Thanks.
I would mark the above suggestion as an answer, but I can't mark a Comment as an Answer. If you want to copy the text to an Answer, I'll get you credit for it.

There is a way to work around it.

The first time the user selects a file, you loop thru the selected directory (!) with the command Dir().
Store the results - the files and paths of subfolders - into a comma seperated string.
Create a seperate form where you have a listbox.
Open the form, even with acDialog.
Feed the stored results as rowsource of the listbox.
Put some code in the name_of_listbox_Click() event

